# contrast mean difference between intervention and control group

Tags: anova, experiment-design, contrasts, observational-study

I'm studying a case of a quasi-experimental design, and have two groups. The Intervention Group and the Control Group. An answer for each individual was measured before and after the intervention (paired). To test whether there are differences between the intervention group and control what is the proper contrast?

For each group (intervention and control groups) compare:
$$\begin{align}
H_0:\mu_{before}=\mu_{after} \\
H_1:\mu_{before}\neq \mu_{after} \\
\end{align}$$
Or only make the contrast:
$$\begin{align}
H_0:\mu_{IG}=\mu_{CG} \\
H_1:\mu_{IG}\neq \mu_{CG} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand your question. The two hypothesis look the same to me. Furthermore, in a two-groups case, contrast is always (+1 and -1) because by definition contrasts are added up to zero.

Comment: I have paired data for each group, so the first contrast is to see whether there are differences between paired data in a group and the other. That is, I am making a contrast within each group. Instead, the second contrast I only calculate the differences between the two groups.